# Get object by hashcode

Tags: c#, hash, hashcode

I don't understand why there isn't a native function to do this.  Suppose that I create the following class:

```
public class Student {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public override int GetHashCode() {
         return(Name.GetHashCode());
     }
}
```

Afterwards, I create a `HashSet` containing a number of students.  Now I want to get a student from the `HashSet` using his name, which is also the hash code used, without enumeration.  Is this possible?  If it is, how would I accomplish this?  Since the name of the student is used as the hash code, this should be possible with an `O(1)` operation, right?

Comment: Use HashSet.Contains().  It is amortized O(1).

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string,Student>` and you can get the value as `myDictionary["name"]`

Comment: @Siriam I suppose that would work, but it would create consistency problems.  What if the key of the dictionary is not the same as the name of the object?  If there's no other workaround I suppose I'll have to settle with this solution.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @Thomas us a `use a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: Please note that O(1) means constant time, not that it is fast.

Comment: @OrestisP. I don't understand. Why do you imagine key is not same as name? In the end you're going to use right? So you need to make sure key is Name.

Comment: Obligatory Eric Lippert link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `HashSet` (or a Dictionary) to store your students use a [KeyedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
public class StudentCollection : KeyedCollection<string, Student>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Student item)
    {
        return student.Name;
    }
}
```

This will let you do lookups by name quickly just like a Dictionary but you don't need to manually pair up the name with the key when you are inserting. But be aware, no two students can have the same name or you will get a error (just the same as if you had a Dictionary and used two students of the same name).

Comment: Not an array of arrays, actually. IIRC, it's an array of linked lists (or something similar to linked lists, anyway).

Comment: I have greatly simplified my answer, if you would like to learn more about how a HashSet works, look at the revision history.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for!  Going to test it now and will probably pick this answer if it's as good as it seems!

Answer (score 5):

A hashcode is **not** a unique identifier. Different objects may have the same hashcode. The only requirement for hashcodes is that objects that are considered equal have the same hashcode.

If you need `O(1)` retrieval of an item based on a key, use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: A hashcode is indeed an identifier. In fact, I can check for the existence of an item in my `HashSet<T>` by comparing hash codes...

Comment: A KeyedCollection would be better than a Dictionary, due to the fact that the key depends on a property of the value.

Comment: @DavidHaney a hashcode does not - and cannot - uniquely identify an item.

Comment: @JonB - this is now an exercise in theory, but... depends how many unique items you have and how colliding your hash alg is. If I have 3 distinct objects with IDs 1, 2, and 3. And their hashcodes are the same as their IDs... You bet it can. :)

Comment: @DavidHaney, a hashcode could possibly be an id for a limited set of objects, if you took care to generate a unique hashcode for each. But it's not true in the general case, since there is a finite number of distinct hashcodes, and an infinite number of possible objects. And even in the cases where it can work, it's certainly not a good idea to use a hashcode as an id, since it's definitely not what it was designed for.

Comment: @DavidHaney, I suggest you read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I suggest you understand the difference between an *identifier* such as a first name which is unique to a set of objects, and a uid or *unique identifier*. Note that I was discussing the former: a hash code is indeed an *identifier* - in fact it would otherwise have no purpose. You use the code to *identify* where to find the object(s).

Comment: @DavidHaney, I edited my answer to say "*unique* identifier". Happy now ? :)

Comment: A dictionary would work but I will have to make sure that the dictionary's key is the same as the student's name, which may result in consistency issues (e.g. When some part of the application changes the student's name).  I could handle this by changing both the student's name and the dictionary's key every time I want to do a modification.  I will use a dictionary if I don't find a better solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @OrestisP., that's why using the name as the key is a very bad idea; your students should have an identifier (integer, Guid, or whatever you want) that will never change.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I was using the student scenario as an example.  In some cases you might want something to be unique but changeable (e.g. Filenames).  I could make sure that whenever the key changes, the student changes as well, but I find it bad practice to unnecessarily store the same thing twice.  A KeyedCollection is what I was looking for.